# How to do validate String using regular expression in java

Tags: java, android, regex, string, validation

Here i want to make regx for string which contains only 0 to 6 numbers only.
This String contains 0 to 6 numbers like that.

```
 Example-1 : "010002030405" Valid String
```

This String contains only o to 6 numbers so here i used this regx `"[0-6]*"`. But one more thing i want to validate in this string, I want 0 only at odd positions 1-6 will not be on odd positions never. 0 can be place on odd and even both but 1-6 will be place only even positions.

Here i given u some valid and invalid string examples

```
Valid : 000102000004
invalid : 0023015006
```

Here i used this code Please suggest me or tell me what i have to change in my regx to satisfy below validation

```
1) String contains only 0-6 numbers nothing else.
2) 1-6 would be only even positions only they would not be at odd position ever, 0 would be odd and even position.
```

**Code :**

```
public boolean isOptions(String input) {
    String patternString = "[0-6]*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    return pattern.matcher(input).matches();
}
```

Comment: "I want 0 only at odd positions 1-6 will not be on odd positions never. 0 can be place on odd and even both" Isn't this a bit contradictory that you want 0 only at odd positions and that 0 can be placed at both odd and even?

Comment: are you really bent upon using regex here? I think simple loop and checking should be much easier here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691519/regular-expression-to-match-only-odd-or-even-number This would help lot to achieve the logic you trying to build

Comment: @Shreya: Wouldn't that also match "022222222"?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Sorry my bad. i want 0 at even and odd both and 1-6 only on even places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't tried this out, but might work:

```
(0[0-6])*0?
```

Comment: how is it ensuring that 1-6 are only at even positions?

Comment: Because first comes a 0 and then anything between 0 and 6. Rinse and repeat (this pattern of 2 digits). Then maybe add a final 0.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks Can u please Explain me this regular expresssion

Comment: This expression matches all strings that have 0 or more times a couple of "0" follow by a digit between 0 and 6; and maybe a trailing 0.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Here i want to check String validation for every 2 places. So what type of modification i have to make change?

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail or open a new question?