# Regular expression for 4 to 30 only with even numbers only in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a fresher in Javascript, I want to write a regular expression for 4 to 30 and only even numbers. I have created a text field in Html and I want to validate based upon the regular expression.

I copied the following one, but it is not working for 4.

```
([12][02468])|([0][68])|([3][0])|(^[68])
```

This regular expression is not accepting 4 as number, it only accepts from 6.
It should except 4 as minimum and other even numbers only, maximum value will be 30.

4, 6,8, 22, 26,24, 30 are allowed.

0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 31 21, 11 are not allowed.

Experts, help to solve this problem in Javascript.

Comment: Why would you need a regex?

Comment: Sir, it is written by some seniors, I need 4 to 30 numbers only.

Comment: @Deba If your seniors told you to use regex for this task and it's not some kind of a quiz or something, they don't know what they're talking about. That being said, if you have to use regex (for some weird reason), you may use something like `^(?:[468]|[12][02468]|30)$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ztqLnW/1

Comment: you mean to get regex for odd numbers between the range 4 - 30?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to match only odd or even number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691519/regular-expression-to-match-only-odd-or-even-number)

Comment: Yes Sir, I need regex for odd numbers between the range 4 - 30

Comment: Ahmed Abdelhameed Sir, it is working. What is better way to achieve it so that I can talk to them as a junior.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Sir, thanks, your regular expression is working fine for me.

Comment: `([12][02468])|([0][68])|([3][0])|(^[468])`, it will also work as per your existing expression.

Comment: let acceptable = (n) => 4<=n && n<=30 && !(n%2);

Comment: @ChrisWesseling, Yes, I like this answer.